# SSRS 2012 - How to pass the CommandText from my Dataset as a report parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

I need to pass the query from my Dataset as a parameter to another report.

I created a parameter with the expression '= Datasets! MyDataSet.CommandText' as default value, but giving preview displays an error: The value expression used for the report parameter 'dsQuery' refers to a dataset. Datasets can not be used in report parameter expressions.

I created a textbox with the same expression and it displays normal, so I changed the parameter expression to 'ReportItems!TextBox1.Value', but continued with similar error.

How to pass the CommandText from my Dataset as a report parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the variable in your other report by just hard-coding the expression in the Value section of the Action settings, which has just worked in the test report I made:

[image]